# How to change the name of columns of a Pandas dataframe when it was saved with "pickle"?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pickle, sklearn-pandas

I saved a Pandas DataFrame with "pickle". When I call it it looks like Figure A (that is alright). But when I want to change the name of the columns it looks like Figure B.
What am I doing wrong? What are the other ways to change the name of columns?

Figure A

[image]

Figure B

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_pickle('/home/myfile')
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=('AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'ALL')) 
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved it.

```
df = pd.read_pickle('/home/myfile')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values*100)
df1.index='Feature' + (df1.index+1).astype(str) 
df1.columns=('AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'ALL')

df1
```

Answer (score 2):

read.pickle  already returns a DataFrame.
And you're trying to create a DataFrame from an existing DataFrame, just with renamed columns. That's not necessary...

As you want to rename all columns:

```
df.columns = ['AWA', 'REM','S1','S2','SWS','ALL']
```

Renaming specific columns in general could be achieved with:

```
df.rename(columns={'REM':'NewColumnName'},inplace=True)
```

[Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Comment: And then, how can I do the multiplication of each value by 100, without creating a new DataFrame?